# "numpy.linspace" for second time after excluding some point by first "linspace"

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

I am building a model and I need to get the positions of some points inside a box (known volume). I am thinking on using
a) `numpy.linspace(start,stop,30)`
b) `numpy.linspace(start,stop,3000)`
from the same box, I think I need a tool to exclude the points from a) process.

Example as [2D]
say that we have a line of length 20, and we need to distribute two types of  lines:
1)10 pieces of 1 length,  2) 4 pieces of 2 length.
-The space between piece(small line)from type 1 and any neighbors is equal whatever the neighbor is type 1 or 2.
-The number of small pieces are equally distributed around type 2 piece.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the box that you are referring to with an example? Maybe provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you please check my edit?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is the only one that worked for me:

1. get the `xyz` file, by any other software like jmole.
2. you have the orientations of the model.
   I wrote the orientations into my program to avoid overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```py
filtered_b = np.setdiff1d(np.linspace(start, stop, 3000), np.linspace(start, stop, 30))
```

This chooces points that are b that are not in a.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Can you please check my edit?

Comment: I do not understand the new question. You should probably search Python `set` if looking more of these operations.